# Postgres performance implications in storing json array data as type jsonb or jsonb[]

Tags: postgresql

considering a model like the below with a json array of **bars**:

```
const myModel = {
   id: 1,
   bars: [
   {
      aproperty: 10
   },
   {
      anotherproperty: 'fred' 
   }]
}
```

are there any performance implications when defining the **bars** column as type of jsonb and simply adding the array as json, or storing the array items within a jsonb[] array?

The bars array will not be modified much and simply firehosed in, but will be queried.

Comment: What kinds of queries will be run?

Answer (score 0):

It's strongly depends on task what you will do over data. JSON is just text with syntax check. Jsonb is recursive binary structure with complex data format. JSON should be shorter, and has fast serialization - but slower parsing. Jsonb should be longer with longer serialization, but parsing (reading) is faster.

The main important differences is smarter indexing on Jsonb.

PostgreSQL nonatomic types are immutable - that's means so update doesn't modify old value - it does copy and new value is updated and stored. On large values the update is very expensive.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was column type `jsonb` vs `jsonb[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pavel, but don’t really see a answer here - my question relates to the implications of a json or jsonb[] type given the scenario above. Max length of bars array would be around 20 items.

Comment: @Chev - nobody knows - probably for some sizes the JSON will be faster, and for some other sizes the Jsonb will be faster. The performance depends on typical size of objects. For these tasks, the real benchmarking is necessary

Comment: Perhaps, it’s not clear but both would be jsonb - jsonb type or jsonb[] type. It’s about storing the property as jsonb or jsonb[] array

Comment: @Chev - again - it depends - if you use jsonb[], then you can get faster number of items, and append can be faster - because the other values are not unpacked. But maybe there will be significant overhead from repeated jsonb header data overhead, and saving longer context can be slower. So check it and you will see. This is a situation where performance depends on more factors and is hard or impossible to say what is a importance of any factor.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "PostgreSQL nonatomic types are immutable"? I'm googling "PostgreSQL atomic immutable" and getting unhelpful results. I'm interested in learning what postgres types are nonatomic.

Comment: @DharmaTurtle - currently all values of all types stored in tables are immutable (what I know). There are more reasons - fundamental is using MVCC architecture. Little bit different environment is PL/pgSQL - row or arrays in plpgsql supports boxing and unboxing and unboxed value is mutable (on modern Postgres). So arrays stored in tables are immutable, plpgsql variables of array type are mutable.